# display file name in url using htaccess and mod re write

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess file which turns this url

```
www.mysite.com/user.php?id=dan
```

into this

```
www.mysite.com/dan
```

But how could i make this so it looks like this

```
www.mysite.com/user/dan
```

Here is my htaccess code so far. So how could i achieve this? any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to format each parameter on a case by case basis in apache so there's no way to do it for /any/ parameter but for your case you can use something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^id=(.*)$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^/user.php$         /user/id/%1/  [NC,L,R=301]
```